# high chart date format in x-axis

Tags: highcharts, google-analytics, column-chart

I am using column chart in highchart in this i want to show x-axis in date format which i fetch from the google analytics data of my account.and i want to view the date on x-axis and which is not coming in format i want it in formatted way.
it comes like this way "20151001" and i want it to be like this "01-10-2015"
my data is come from google analytic account so i cant use highchart data
this is my code for this

php code from which i get date

```
     $matrics='ga:sessions,ga:pageviews';
     $results_top_pages = $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:109200082',
     date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-6 days')),
     date('Y-m-d',strtotime('now')),
     $matrics,
      array(

        'dimensions' => 'ga:date',
       // 'sort' => '-ga:pageviews', for acsending and decending page view sorting
    'filters'=>'ga:browser%3D~%5E'.$browser.'',
        'max-results' => 50
     ));

  if(is_array($results_top_pages->getRows())){
      echo '<ol>';
      foreach($results_top_pages->getRows() as $top_page){
        echo '<li>';
        echo $top_page[0];
        echo ' - '.$top_page[1].' ';
        echo ' - '.$top_page[2].' ';
        $data[]=$top_page[2];
        $date[]=$top_page[0];
        echo '</li>';
        }
         echo '</ol>';
     }
```

by var_dump of $date i get date in this format:

```
    array(7) {
   [0]=>
   string(8) "20150930"
   [1]=>
   string(8) "20151001"
   [2]=>
   string(8) "20151002"
   [3]=>
   string(8) "20151003"
   [4]=>
   string(8) "20151004"
   [5]=>
    string(8) "20151005"
   [6]=>
   string(8) "20151006"
   }
```

### Edited code from here

::

```
    This is js code for highchart:

       $data[]=$top_page[2];
      $date[]=date('d-m-y',strtotime($top_page[0]));

       // echo '</li>';
         }
          echo '</ol>';
      }
      var_dump($date[0]);
       $datefirst= date('U', strtotime($date[0])) * 1000;

     ?>

    <script>

     $(function () {

        $('#container').highcharts({
         //alert("call");

     chart: {
         type: 'column'
     },
     title: {
        text: 'Weekly Traffic'
     },
     subtitle: {
         //text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
      },
      xAxis: {

        categories: [<?php echo join($date,','); ?>],
        max:6
       },
      yAxis: {
            title: {
            text: 'Views'
        }
      }, 
       plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            connectNulls: false
             },
             enableMouseTracking: false
           }
       },
       series: [{
       pointStart: '<?php echo $datefirst; ?>',
        pointInterval: 86400000, //one day
        pointRange: 86400000, //one day
        name: '<?php echo $browser; ?>',
        data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>],
        //pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 1),
        //  pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
       },

       ]
        });
        });
       </script>
      <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: So, it looks like you just need to format the dates before you add them to the $date array?

Comment: Though I would also suggest, since you are plotting datetime data, that you switch from a category axis to a datetime axis - http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type

Comment: yes i want it to be in format and my date doesnt come in format i have also used datetime axis but it doesnt match with my data

Comment: Right, so you just need to use the date() function on the value before adding it to the $date array, just like you used it before:  date('Y-m-d',strtotime('now')) - except instead of 'now', you supply the date value you are trying to format.  If that doesn't work, you may need to use substr() to break the date string into its different parts, and build the desired date string yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, working from your example, you just need to format the dates properly.

Something like this:

```
foreach($results_top_pages->getRows() as $top_page){
    echo '<li>';
    echo $top_page[0];
    echo ' - '.$top_page[1].' ';
    echo ' - '.$top_page[2].' ';
    $data[]=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($top_page[2])); //add the date function
    $date[]=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($top_page[0])); //add the date function 
    echo '</li>';
    }
     echo '</ol>';
 }
```

If you want to use a `datetime` x axis type, which I would suggest any time you're displaying time series data, you would just change the format to use  millisecond epoch time, like this:

```
date('U', strtotime($top_page[2])) * 1000
```

But instead of building an array of categories, you would set that value as the x value of your data.

Alternatively, if the data is always going to be a daily value, you can set your `pointStart` property as the start time, and your `pointInterval` property as 1 day (86400000 milliseconds)

**{{edit ----------**

An example of the last method:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/xabj5qgp/

You supply:

1. A start datetime stamp in epoch format
2. An interval between points (ie one day - in milliseconds)
3. Your array of data points, one data point per interval (day)

The chart does the rest.

**{{Edit for comments:**

So, you can put the pointStart and pointInterval properties in one of two places - either in the plotOptions, or in the series properties directly.
pointRange isn't necessarily required, but it is usually a good idea as it fixes some potential spacing issues with columns/bars.

So in your case, take this:

```
series: [{
    name: '<?php echo $browser; ?>',
    data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]
},
```

And add the properties there:

```
series: [{
    pointStart: __your_start_date__,
    pointInterval: 86400000, //one day
    pointRange: 86400000, //one day
    name: '<?php echo $browser; ?>',
    data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]
},
```

You will need to retrieve that start date from your data source and format it as epoch time in milliseconds (as demonstrated above)

Comment: Can you put this in my highchart code actually i am new to jquery and highchart i am not getting it where to put if you can do this for me it would be great for me.

Comment: but i have dynamic start point which comes from the analytic account so how can i set static time set in x-axis?is there any way to show time from google analytic date rather then static date start?

Comment: Yes, you just set that pointStart variable based on the dynamic date from your data source. See updated answer.

Comment: but in that case i am getting date -16 look one time the code that i apply here

Comment: echo out the value of $datefirst and post it

Comment: currently i am getting -13 in x-axis not any other value is view on the x-axis

Comment: by doing echo of $datefirst i get this kind of output

Comment: and in x-axis it view -13 in the output

Comment: I think you'll need to set up a fiddle, or link to a live example.  You can set up a fiddle by loading your chart on your page, view source, and copy the chart options from the output code.  That we can see all of your options, as well as the formatted data that is coming through.

Comment: js fiddle for this is given below

Comment: now my problem is resolved many many thanks..working  fiddle link is here